# Searching for most performant way for string replacing with javascript

Tags: javascript, string

I'm programming my own autocomplete textbox control using C# and javascript on clientside. On client side i want to replace the characters in string which matching the characters the user was searching for to highlight it. For example if the user was searching for the characters 'bue' i want to replace this letters in the word 'marbuel' like so:

```
mar<span style="color:#81BEF7;font-weight:bold">bue</span>l
```

in order to give the matching part another color. This works pretty fine if i have 100-200 items in my autocomplete, but when it comes to 500 or more, it takes too mutch time.

The following code shows my method which does the logic for this:

```
 HighlightTextPart: function (text, part) {
    var currentPartIndex = 0;
    var partLength = part.length;
    var finalString = '';
    var highlightPart = '';
    var bFoundPart = false;
    var bFoundPartHandled = false;
    var charToAdd;
    for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
        var myChar = text[i];
        charToAdd = null;
        if (!bFoundPart) {
            var myCharLower = myChar.toLowerCase();
            var charToCompare = part[currentPartIndex].toLowerCase();
            if (charToCompare == myCharLower) {
                highlightPart += myChar;
                if (currentPartIndex == partLength - 1)
                    bFoundPart = true;

                currentPartIndex++;
            }
            else {
                currentPartIndex = 0;
                highlightPart = '';
                charToAdd = myChar;
            }
        }
        else
            charToAdd = myChar;

        if (bFoundPart && !bFoundPartHandled) {
            finalString += '<span style="color:#81BEF7;font-weight:bold">' + highlightPart + '</span>';
            bFoundPartHandled = true;
        }

        if (charToAdd != null)
            finalString += charToAdd;
    }
    return finalString;
},
```

This method only highlight the first occurence of the matching part.
I use it as follows. Once the request is coming back from server i build an html UL list with the matching items by looping over each item and in each loop i call this method in order to highlight the matching part.

As i told for up to 100 items it woks pretty nice but it is too mutch for 500 or more.

Is there any way to make it faster? Maybe by using regex or some other technique?

I also thought about using "setTimeOut" to do it in a extra function or maybe do it only for the items, which currently are visible, because only a couple of items are visible while for the others you have to scroll.

Comment: There is no C# here. I retagged to JS. +1

Comment: For check code and improve it you can ask on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @WooCaSh: I think it's a valid SO question, since the problem is clearly outlined. OP is not asking to review all coding aspects.

Comment: @Neolisk Yes and no. This part of question: `Is there any way to make it faster? Maybe by using regex or some other technique?` suggest me codereview. But here is also good place for asking.

Comment: @WooCaSh: Put another way, OP has higher chances to get an answer here in reasonable time. No offence to CodeReview, but I find that more people are following SO.

Answer (score 0):

Try limiting visible list size, so you are only showing 100 items at maximum for example. From a usability standpoint, perhaps even go down to only 20 items, so it would be even faster than that. Also consider using classes - see if it improves performance. So instead of

```
mar<span style="color:#81BEF7;font-weight:bold">bue</span>l
```

You will have this:

```
mar<span class="highlight">bue</span>l
```

Comment: thx.. i changed it by using a css class. for the main problem i think, im going to use a smaller amount of autocomplete items. As i told 200 items works pretty fine but i think 200 items also is too much in order to ensure usability. but im still surprised how many time it takes to handle this for more items. but i have no idea how to increase performance. maybe i try the suggestion to do it on demand while user is scrolling for only a cuple of items. thx and regards.

Answer (score 0):

String replacement in JavaScript is pretty easy with [`String.replace()`](https://www.google.com.sg/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC8QFjAA&url=https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace&ei=9jyFUaGKFs3IrQfVvYCwBQ&usg=AFQjCNEUptb04sNzfsj34_TYgjMDYfrbgg&bvm=bv.45960087,d.bmk):

```
function linkify(s, part)
{
    return s.replace(part, function(m) {
        return '<span style="color:#81BEF7;font-weight:bold">' + htmlspecialchars(m) + '</span>';
    });
}

function htmlspecialchars(txt)
{
    return txt.replace('<', '&lt;')
        .replace('>', '&gt;')
        .replace('"', '&quot;')
        .replace('&', '&amp;');
}

console.log(linkify('marbuel', 'bue'));
```

Comment: thx for respond. the method "replace" was something i also tried. but it seems to be not faster as my code above. regards!

Comment: @Marbuel that's probably because replace() always returns a new string so if there are no matches it returns the same string which would be slow. You could do matching first and then perform replacement where necessary.

Comment: That was also a way i tried. Go through all autocomplete items and evaluate substring index to replace first, than concatenate my final string by using the function "substring()". I tried everything im familiar with, but wasn't able to improve the performance. Another thing i do not understand is, that the time it takes until browser again is responding and the list will be completely constructed is increasing exponentially with the amount of items. While 200 items seems nearly to be handled without delay, 500 takes one second or often a bit more. That makes me a little confused.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem by using regex instead of my method posted previous. I replace the string now with the following code:

```
return text.replace(new RegExp('(' + part + ')', 'gi'), "<span>$1</span>");
```

This is pretty fast. Much faster as the code above. 500 items in the autocomplete seems to be no problem. But can anybody explain, why this is so mutch faster as my method or doing it with string.replace without regex? I have no idea.

Thx!